# Best practise and methods for Kafka parameters and monitoring

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am going to implement a Snowflake Kafka connector with the continuous ingestion of data to target database snowflake.

What are the best practices for :

1. Kafka for its clusters
2. Kafka and its related parameters
3. Monitoring resources

Answer (score 0):

> Kafka for its clusters

Run at least 3 brokers

> Kafka and its related parameters

That's too broad and has nothing to do with running a Connect cluster or implementing one. The defaults are mostly fine. You can find the production recommendations in the Kafka documentation.

> Monitoring resources

Use JMX. https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/monitoring.html

> going to implement a Snowflake Kafka connector

Snowflake already has a connector... I'd start by forking rather than making your own